# Do I need a new Bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth, htc-droid-incredible

I just picked up an HTC Droid Incredible a few days ago. I already had a Plantronics Discovery 975 headset, which I like, so I've been trying to use it with the phone. It pairs fine and does work, but I've been having some problems that make it not very usable.

**Problem 1:** The "Bluetooth in-call volume" always goes to minimum between calls, and I can't hear the voice prompts. It doesn't matter whether I raise the volume using the Bluetooth or the handset, it always goes back to minimum on the next call.

**Problem 2:** The standard Navigation app (Google Maps Navigation for mobile) doesn't work with the Bluetooth at all (even if I make sure it's connected before starting of the Navigation app). I have to speak into the handset and all sound comes out through the phone's speaker. I can't find any setting to change this.

**Problem 3:** The Voice Dialer also doesn't work through the Bluetooth. The only way I can use the Voice Dialer is to hold the main button on my Bluetooth for 3 seconds. If I activate it from the phone, I have to speak into the handset.

Does this mean my Discovery is just not compatible with the phone or is there something I can do with settings to get it to work properly?

If I do need a new Bluetooth, can you recommend one that works well with an Android phone (or even better, one that works well with an Incredible)?

Comment: Not really an answer - but if you can I'd suggest getting another (borrow someones?) bluetooth headset to see if you have the same problems, that would determine if it is the headset or the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, for Navigation directions over BT you need A2DP (just like music).  I just checked [the specs on Plantronics' website for the Discovery 975](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/discovery-975) and it doesn't mention having this.

There's also a setting somewhere in Navigation to route it over the speaker or the headset; I remember turning it off on mine because it was interrupting conversations when I was trying to listen.  Unfortunately I can't recall exactly where the setting is; I'll update this later if I find it again.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some issues with the fact that Android's bluetooth was not up to date. Testing your phone with another headset would be a first step in singling out the problem. Also, try to see if you can go to your local authorized reseller or a carrier store to see if a technician can have a look at it.